# Amazon Pinpoint SMS For India

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to implement Amazon's Pinpoint SMS. There is a special requirement for India to send SMS. I have followed this [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-senderid-india.html) and added EntityId and TemplateId as extra parameters to `pinpoint.sendMessages`. But when I do, I am getting.

> - UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'EntityId' found in params.MessageRequest.MessageConfiguration.SMSMessage
> - UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'TemplateId' found in params.MessageRequest.MessageConfiguration.SMSMessage

**Code**

Refrence: [AWS Official Pinpoint SMS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sms.html)

```
 let params = {
            ApplicationId: applicationId,
            MessageRequest: {
                Addresses: {
                    [destinationNumber]: {
                        ChannelType: 'SMS'
                    }
                },
                MessageConfiguration: {
                    SMSMessage: {
                        Body: body,
                        EntityId: entityID,
                        Keyword: registeredKeyword,
                        MessageType: messageType,
                        OriginationNumber: originationNumber,
                        SenderId: senderId,
                        TemplateId: templateID
                      },
                }
            }
        };

        //Try to send the message.
        pinpoint.sendMessages(params, function (err, data) {
            // If something goes wrong, print an error message.
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                // Otherwise, show the unique ID for the message.
            } else {
                console.log(data)
                // console.log("Message sent! "
                //     + data['MessageResponse']['Result'][destinationNumber]['StatusMessage']);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrating `AWS-SDK` from `2.467.0` to `2.850` solved my issue.